# Git checkout branch from old tag

Tags: git, kernel, branching-and-merging

I'm trying to checkout a new branch from old tags in the [linux kernel git project](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git).

I can checkout `v2.6.13` just fine:

```
$ git checkout -b build-2.6.13 v2.6.13
```

But when I try to create a branch from tag `v2.6.11`, I get this error:

```
$ git checkout -b build-2.6.11 v2.6.11
fatal: Cannot switch branch to a non-commit 'v2.6.11'
```

I have also tried using `refs/tags/v2.6.11` and `tags/v2.6.11` as the tag reference, both return the same error.

I'd like to know why creating a branch from this tag fails.

Comment: Something is wrong, v.2.6.11 does not point to a commit. If you check here http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/refs/ and search for 2.6.11 it points to a tree and not a commit, and if you click that (http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/?id=c39ae07f393806ccf406ef966e9a15afc43cc36a) it throws invalid commit reference. It seems like that commit is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tag [points to a tree object, not a commit object](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tag/?h=v2.6.11):

> NOTE! There's no commit for this, since it happened before I started with git.
>   Eventually we'll import some sort of history, and that should tie this tree
>   object up to a real commit. In the meantime, this acts as an anchor point for
>   doing diffs etc under git.

I'm not sure if the "import some sort of history" step is something that you can do as an end user. If it is, I don't know how to do it.

The [link to the tagged tree](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/?h=v2.6.11&id=c39ae07f393806ccf406ef966e9a15afc43cc36a) doesn't seem to be valid, either:

> Invalid commit reference: c39ae07f393806ccf406ef966e9a15afc43cc36a

That's not a good sign. Unfortunately, the answer might be that you won't be able to track this version of the Linux source code down.